# how to deyploy app to mobilefirst production server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I was working on Android Mobile first app which was connecting to development server until now. I got the production server url today and I was trying to push the app to the production server, I was able to deploy app on production server but nothing works there when I run my app.

Procedure I followed:

1. URL: https://MYServer:10080/worklightconsole
2. Changed details in Wlclient.properties

> ```
> wlServerProtocol=http
> wlServerHost=MYServer
> wlServerPort=10080
> wlServerContext=/MYAPP/
> wlAppId=com_myapp
> wlAppVersion=1.0
> wlEnvironment=Androidnative
> wlUid=wY/mbnwKTDDYQUodidsdSgg==
> wlPlatformVersion=7.1.0.00.20150913-2345
> wl.analytics.console.url=l=https://MYServer:10080/analytics/console
> wl.analytics.url=l=https://MYServer:10080/analytics/analytics-service/data
> ```

3. I did a mfp push to my development server.
4. Took the myapp.wlapp and  deployed  into production server.

But this is not working because when check my wlclient.properties file after mfpush it changes the host port and protocol.

Can anyone help me understanding how do the push the app to the production server and get it worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure to update the wlclient.properties file in your Android project with the correct server details post build. You can do this either manually of by automating it with Ant script tasks and such.

Comment: I Have tried the way you have told me to do .. but now I am getting  javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Cannot verify hostname: myserver.sample.com .I am trying to connect to https server